# Figaro not using correct environment variable when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, environment-variables, figaro-ruby

For some reason Figaro is not setting my `DATABASE_URL` properly when testing.  It uses the development `DATABASE_URL` for some reason.  Here's the final few rows of my `application.yml`:

```
development:
  DATABASE_URL:               'postgres:///xxx-development'

test:
  DATABASE_URL:               'postgres:///xxx_test'
```

In my test I added a few print lines to help debug:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'json'
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe 'HealthProfile::HealthProfileTypeformParser' do
    
    before(:all) do
        p "ENV", ENV['RAILS_ENV'], ENV['DATABASE_URL']
        # prints "ENV", "test", "postgres:///xxx-development"
    end
 end
```

It makes no sense as clearly the environement is being set.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What version of `figaro` are you using? Also do you have any of these configs in your application.yml?

Comment: It's v1.2.  Not sure what you mean by "these configs".  I have a typo up there.  Should have been `application.yml`, not `database.yml`.

Comment: check your `database.yml` and see if you setting the correct `url` key for the `test` environment. based on your configuration, it should be `url: 'postgres:///xxx_test'`

Comment: It uses `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` in the `database.yml`

Comment: Even when I hard code it in `database.yml` it still picks up `postgres:///xxx-development`

Comment: I had to add this to `spec_helper` to get it working but I have no idea why?  Does anyone know why this would be necessary? `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path("../../lib/my_gem_config/database.yml", __FILE__)))["test"])`